# Why does multi-catch feature in Java require exceptions to be final?

Tags: java, exception, java-7, multi-catch

The Oracle documentation on the [multi-catch feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) added to Java 7 states that the exception parameter in the `catch` clause is implicitly `final`.

My question is: **what's the point of such restriction**? Because i can't seem to find a single crucial improvement it brings. Marking a reference object as `final` only protects the reference itself from being modified, not the object it references, and one is never prohibited to create another reference and modify it in whatever way they want.

A [somewhat relevant question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959436/java-catch-block-caught-exception-is-not-final) discusses the reasons why modifying the exception reference in a `catch` clause is not the wisest thing to do, but it relates to *any* use of the `catch` clause, not just the multi-catch form of it. So why does Java make an, ahem, exception for the multi-catch and treat it in a special way?

Comment: Not much you can typically assign to a variable with a type union.

Comment: I assume it has to do with the fact, that the type is not clear in the multi-catch.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16960774/438154) answer in the question you've linked gives an explanation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, if by the explanation you mean the phrase " There's not a lot of point in debating the apparent inconsistencies ... unless you are intending to design and implement a new language", then i beg to differ. Knowing the logic behind a certain language construct helps understanding the language designers' way of thinking, which helps using the language in a more proper and idiomatic way.

Comment: No, this _On the other hand, allowing modification in the multi-exception catch would introduces the possibility of truly bizarre and confusing code such as this:_.

Comment: Okay, you have a point. Still, i disagree that this question is a duplicate. The fact that some secondary answer to a different question provided the answer for this one doesn't mean this question is not useful. For example, it helps finding the proper answer by asking the particular question explicitly.

Comment: A duplicate is not a bad things. Duplicates don't get deleted. They remain there as flagposts to the actual answer. But I've reopened.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the uni-catch clause, you are free to re-assign the exception object. For example, this works fine:

```
try {
    ... // code that can throw IOException or some user-defined ParserException
} catch(IOException) {
    e = new IOException();  // this is acceptable (although there is no point in doing it)
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The compiler knows for sure that the thrown object is of type `IOException`.
However, in the multi-catch clause, you can have something like:

```
try {
    ... // code that can throw IOException or some user-defined ParserException
} catch(IOException | ParserException e) {
    e = new IOException(); // this is NOT acceptable -- e may reference a ParserException
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this case, the compiler has no idea which type the exception is at compile-time, so assigning a new `IOException` to a variable that can reference *either* an `IOException` or `ParseException` should not be allowed. Added to that is the lack of use-cases for assigning to the exception variable in the first place. Therefore it makes perfect sense to make the variable implicitly `final` and avoid all of this confusion. If you really need to assign to the variable, you can switching to the old way of writing sequence of `catch` blocks.